# How can I convert the below oracle hint sql query to Querydsl code

Tags: optimization, querydsl, hint

How can I convert the below sql to Querydsl code?
(convert oracle optimizer hint to querydsl code)

SAL column of the EMP table has been created , the index of idx_emp_sal name.

create index idx_emp_sal on emp(sal);

select  /*+ index_desc(emp idx_emp_sal) */
        ename, sal
from    emp
where   sal > 0;

Answer (score 0):

You can add Oracle query hints with the addFlags feature in your querydsl

For example

```
 .addFlag(AFTER_SELECT, "/*+ index_desc(emp idx_emp_sal) */ ")
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand completely your SQL query, but should be something like this.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT ename, sal 
FROM emp
WHERE sal > 0
ORDER BY sal DESC
```

**QueryDSL**

```
QEmp qemp = QEmp.emp;
jpaQuery.from(qemp)
        .where(qemp.sal.gt(0))
        .orderBy(qemp.sal.desc())
        .select(qemp.ename, qemp.sal)
        .fetch();
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to use Oracle Hints statement. Without the order by